# warning: variance matrix is nonsymmetric or highly singular

Tags: instrumental-variables, 2sls

I get the above warning when running a 2SLS regression in Stata with robust standard errors. Specifically, I get this for the first stage, where in addition the first stage has no F-statistic, p-value, standard errors, t-values or confidence interval.

To give more context, my instrument is random assignment of treatment while my endogenous variable is whether the subject complied with the treatment (i.e. completed the intended treatment). What could be the cause of this? Is there a fundamental problem with using assigned treatment as an instrument? Is there a more elaborate method to obtain Complier Average Causal Effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is compliance perfect, i.e. everybody who is told to get treatment does so and everybody who is told not do does not, so that the first stage has perfect fit? With zero residuals in the first stage, one can then by extension also not compute t or F statistics etc.

Incidentally, we then also have 2SLS = OLS, and in any event, a 2SLS approach seems redundant under perfect compliance, as it is designed to handle the consequences of non-perfect compliance. Under perfect compliance, OLS is just fine.

This argument and the example below also demonstrate that the issue appears to be unrelated to robust errors.

Example:

```
library(ivmodel)
n <- 100
Z <- sample(c(0,1), n, replace=T)
X <- Z
y <- rnorm(n)
> summary(lm(y~X))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ X)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.14902 -0.90276  0.00966  0.80308  2.97005 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  -0.1935     0.1626  -1.191    0.237
X             0.2280     0.2254   1.011    0.314

Residual standard error: 1.126 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.01033,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.0002302 
F-statistic: 1.023 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 0.3143

> ivmodel(y, X, Z)

Call:
ivmodel(Y = y, D = X, Z = Z)
sample size: 100
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

First Stage Regression Result:

F=-3.825057e+16, df1=1, df2=98, p-value is 1
R-squared=1,   Adjusted R-squared=1
Residual standard error: NaN on 99 degrees of freedom
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

Coefficients of k-Class Estimators:

               k  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
OLS    0.000e+00 2.280e-01  2.254e-01   1.011    0.314
TSLS   1.000e+00 2.280e-01  2.254e-01   1.011    0.314
Fuller 7.037e+13 2.392e-01  2.254e-01   1.061    0.291
LIML   7.037e+13 2.392e-01  2.254e-01   1.061    0.291
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

Alternative tests for the treatment effect under H_0: beta=0.

Anderson-Rubin test (under F distribution):
F=1.022796, df1=1, df2=98, p-value is 0.31435
95 percent confidence interval:
 [-0.219390069608376, 0.675394290189136]

Conditional Likelihood Ratio test (under Normal approximation):
Test Stat=0, p-value is 1
95 percent confidence interval:
 [NA, NA]
Warning message:
In sqrt(SSE/DE) : NaNs produced
```